# unexpected output of 2d array in py-script

Tags: pyscript

this is sample of my code where i actually face this missbehavior

```
<py-script>
rows, cols = (3, 3)
board = [[-1]*cols]*rows
print(board)
board[0][2]=2
print(board)
</py-script>
```

it is only happen within pyscript i try the same code in python outside    pyscript and
and there i got the desire output but not here

and the output is

```
[[-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1]]
[[-1, -1, 2], [-1, -1, 2], [-1, -1, 2]]
```

and i expected `
[[-1, -1, 2], [-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1]]

why it changes all rows value of that perticular column

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in how your constructing your board, in this line: `board = [[-1]*cols]*rows`.

The goal (I'm assuming) is to have a list of three distinct "rows", each of which is a list of three numbers set to -1. However, the line above creates a single list `[-1, -1, -1]`, and creates a list `board` which is *three references to that same list*. You can see this by checking whether the three members of board are the same object using `is`:

```py
rows, cols = (3, 3)
board = [[-1]*cols]*rows
print(board[0] is board[1] is board[2]) #true
```

When you using `board[0][2]` to change the third element of the first row, you change the third element of the *only* row that's in your list, so all the rows appear to change.

To achieve what you're looking for, where each row is unique, use a list comprehension:

```py
rows, cols = (3, 3)
board = [[-1 for c in range(cols)] for r in range(rows)]
print(board)
board[0][2]=2
print(board)

# Output:
# [[-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1]]
# [[-1, -1, 2], [-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1]]
```

This is not specific to PyScript, but true in Python in general.